# How do you create an array of emails in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, activerecord, models

I am trying to create an array of emails from my user model, with a helper method to access them. I will then load this array into a drop down selector. I am new to rails, and the MVC framework is new to me also.

#### In my application_helper.rb

```
  def create_user_selector_array
    @user = User.select(:email).distinct
  end
```

#### In my _form.html.erb partial

```
<%= f.select(:associate, @user.map { |value| [ value, value ] }) %>
<%= @user %>
```

What appears to be happing when I launch this site, is that my selector contains this:

```
#<User:>(Characters)
```

And when I pull just the array it prints this:

```
ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_User:0x007fb28894d508>
```

I feel close, but I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Rails 3.2 and newer, you can use `pluck`:

```
User.pluck(:email)
# => ["foo@example.com", "bar@example.com"]
```

Otherwise, your solution just needed a `map`:

```
@user = User.select(:email).distinct.map(&:email)
```

Using `select` just determines what fields get returned, however you still get an array of ActiveRecord objects, not strings like you were expecting.